# How can you get hard mode in Golden Sun the Lost Age without completing the game?

Tags: golden-sun-the-lost-age

My first thought is to download someone else's emulator save file with completed game. I use emulator Mednafen so preferably working with that but initial searches haven't turned up anything. Where could I find such a save file, or alternatively a cheat/hack, or what other method to get hard mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a save file at http://www.zophar.net/savestates/gba/golden-sun-the-lost-age.html which worked with Mednafen (I think most emulators might work with the same format) at the end of the game. I finished the game and saved a clear data file so now have access to hard (and easy) mode. I submitted my save with clear data which will hopefully appear there too soon for anyone else who wants hard mode.